# Calling a specific div onclick

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-ui

I'm having more than two forms my page and with one i've there's a script attached that onsubmit it should show a successful message in a div. But when i click on any of the submit buttons on the page, the successful message in the div shows up. this is my code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").on('submit',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        data = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "insert_call_love.asp",
        data: data
        }).success(function() {

            $("#feedback").append("<div class='messages' style='border:1px purple solid; padding:2px; margin:5px;'>You have Loved this photo</div>");

            setTimeout(function() { 
                $(".messages").fadeOut(function(){
                    $(".messages").remove();
                }); 
            }, 1000);

            $("input[type=text]").val("");

        });
    });
});
</script>
```

and someone told me to change from the one above to this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form3").on('submit',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        data = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "insert_call_love.asp",
        data: data
        }).success(function() {

            $("#feedback").append("<div class='messages' style='border:1px purple solid; padding:2px; margin:5px;'>You have Loved this photo</div>");

            setTimeout(function() { 
                $(".messages").fadeOut(function(){
                    $(".messages").remove();
                }); 
            }, 1000);

            $("input[type=text]").val("");

        });
    });
});
</script>
```

HTML

```
<form id="form3" name="form3" method="POST" action="<%=MM_editAction%>">
          <input type="image" name="imageField2" id="imageField2" src="imgs/buttons/loveit.png" />
          <input name="lemail" type="hidden" id="lemail" value="1" />
          <input name="lfname" type="hidden" id="lfname" value="2" />
          <input name="lpic" type="hidden" id="lpic" value="3" />
          <input name="lresp_email" type="hidden" id="lresp_email" value="4" />
          <input name="lwardr" type="hidden" id="lwardr" value="5" />
        </form>
```

specifying the form_id for example my formid is form3 but with that when i even click on submit it doesn't even work

Comment: Do you have any HTML to go with this?

Comment: `$('form3')` is looking for a `<form3>` element, which doesn't exist. If that's an `id`, it should be `#form3` or if it's a class it should be `.form3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the JQuery 'on submit' from:

```
$("form3").on('submit',function(event)
```

to this:

```
 $("#form3").on('submit',function(event)
```

PS: Make sure that the id is unique in the page